# Mailpoet and removing unwanted WordPress users?

Tags: wordpress, email

We are setting up a BuddyBoss membership area for my wife's site. We are going to use the Memberpress integration. The best option for email for her is MailPoet. We tried MailPoet a few months ago, but it automatically imports all of her WordPress users, even if they are not on her current mailing list.

She doesn't want to pay for WP Users when she doesn't understand why they are automatically being added to her MailPoet email list.

There are 1,530 Users listed under All. Subscriber says 241 and Customer says 1,296. Where are the Customers coming from? She has a WooCommerce Shop, but we can't seem to find a direct connection between Woo Customers and the Customers listed under WP Users.

Is there a way we can safely purge some of her WP Users? Or should we just leave them alone and carry them as dead weight? We cannot figure out the point of having them there. She also isn't sure she can legally email them if they haven't double opted-in or they have have subscribed to her email at one time and unsubscribed.

She really likes MailPoet, but it doesn't make sense to have all these WP Users on her MailPoet system if they aren't actually people she is emailing to.

Comment: You could export the users to csv (i.e. using this [plugin](https://wordpress.org/plugins/export-wp-users-xml-csv/) ) and then have a look at those 'old' users. This should make the decision on what to do with them easier.

Answer (score 0):

Actually we're not going to use MailPoet for another reason, so this question is no longer valid.